# JMS message selector wildcard

Tags: java, jms

[This link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncer/index.html) says that message selector can be written as `NewsType = ’Sports’ OR NewsType = ’Opinion’`

Can I use message selector for any NewsType value like

```
NewsType = *
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the syntax of the expression is based on a subset of the SQL92 conditional expression syntax. It can done by using.

```
NewsType LIKE  '%'
```

[Ref](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031980_.htm)

Comment: Your answer posted 1 second before the other answer so you get the upvote, plus you provided a reference. :)

Answer (score 4):

No you can't. As the link says: **The syntax .. is based on .. the SQL92 conditional expression syntax**, so you would have to use

```
NewsType LIKE '%'
```

although I don't quite see why you would need a selector for that?

Cheers,